# How to check whether object is empty in handlebars if statement?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, handlebars.js

In handlebars i need to check if an object is empty and if it isn't then i need to run a loop to grab the content from the object. Below is my code and a link to codepen. I imagine this is quite simple but nothing seems to work. I would have thought that the handlebars #if statement would see an empty object as undefined or 0 and ultimately the condition would be unfulfilled.

```
<div class="temp"></div>

<script id="temp" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#if tabs}}
    <p>true</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#temp").html());

var tabs = {};

var context = {
    tabs: tabs
}

$('.temp').html(template(context));
```

http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/gaKyKv?editors=101

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the built in handlebars `each` helper to accomplish what you're looking for, and you can even conditionally render something with an empty object:

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#temp").html());

var tabs = {},
    test = {a: "Resources", b: "Contact"};

var context = {
    tabs: tabs,
    test: test
}

$('.temp').html(template(context));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div class="temp"></div>

<script id="temp" type="x-handlebars-template">
    <h3>each helper on empty object</h3>
    {{#each tabs}}
        <p>Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>Your tabs object is empty!</p>
    {{/each}}
    
    <h3>each helper on non-empty object</h3>
    {{#each test}}
        <p>Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>Your test object is empty!</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but i'm already using an each, part of my markup needs to exist outside of the each. This means i'd have to use 2 each's which, if theres data, display more markup than i need. So i do really need an if or custom helper. http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/gaKyKv?editors=101

Comment: Is it just that you need to hide the class if the object is empty? if so you can wrap just that `class="..."` inside of the `if` helper.  If not, can you give an example in the question of what you expect the resulting markup to look like individually  in the empty object and non-empty object cases?

Comment: Hi Nick, Is there anyway to check if an object is empty without using an each helper? The reason I cant just use an each helper as you have shown is because I have a wrapper I don't want to be output if the object if empty. Check the latest codepen and you should be able to see from the markup my issue. I'll add some comments in too. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's an easy way to do that in handlebars as is, as both {} and {a: "test"} are considered "true" in the `if`/`unless` helpers, and similarly in the `with` helper.  Your choices are to either 1) build a custom helper, or 2) use one someone else has built already, e.g. http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-collections.html#-empty-, but I don't think this is possible with just the core handlebars library.  It would be much easier if the object just didn't exist, rather than existing and being empty.